# Does RSpec's seed maintain order even if rerunning with a subset of tests?

Tags: rspec

I have some tests that fail intermittently in RSpec because of test ordering (if I rerun the suite with `rspec --seed 1234 spec` I can reproduce the failures every time). While debugging and fixing this, I'd like to limit the tests I run for a faster feedback loop to only the ones causing the failure.

For example, I have some tests failing under `spec/models` if I run the full suite (`rspec --seed 1234 spec`) but passing if I run `rspec --seed 1234 spec/models`.

I'm trying to work out whether that is because it was a test outside of `spec/models` that was causing the initial failure *OR* if the seed is based on the tests chosen.

So, will RSpec re-run the subset in the same order they ran originally or is ordering only guaranteed if I run literally the same suite (e.g. it's some combination of the seed & a hash of the test suite)?

Comment: you can use `--bisect` flag to create a minimal repro case for the ordering dependency.
`rspec --seed 1234 --bisect`
[bisect-rspec-doc](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-9/docs/command-line/bisect#use-%60--bisect%60-flag-to-create-a-minimal-repro-case-for-the-ordering-dependency)

Comment: oh interesting, thanks @LuisSilva! So it feels like that it _does_ maintain ordering or else the `bisect`  flag wouldn't work. Missed this in the docs :) If you add as an answer, happy to accept.

Comment: I did it, regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does.

But you can use `--bisect` flag to create a minimal repo case for ordering dependency, instead of doing manually.

`rspec --seed 1234 --bisect`